# getting an error TypeError: StructType can not accept object 'anu' in type <class 'str'>

Tags: python, pyspark

I am trying to creating a DataFrame in pyspark. I'm using the following code:

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, StructField, StructType

schema=StructType([StructField('name', StringType())])
data=[('anu')]


from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("testing").getOrCreate()
spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)
```

But I get this error:

```py
StructType can not accept object 'anu' in type <class 'str'>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the problem: when defining a one-item tuple, you need to add a `,` at the end. Otherwise, python will assume you are using the parenthesis to specify evaluation order. Here is an example:

```py
>>> type((5))
int
```

Adding the trailing `,`:

```py
>>> type((5,))
tuple
```

What you think data is: `data = [('anu')]`. What data really is: `data = ['anu']`. So you are passing a list of strings, not a list of tuples.

This is what you should do:

```py
>>> schema=StructType([StructField('name', StringType())])
>>> data=[('anu',)]
>>> spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
>>> spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)
```

Answer (score 0):

When we have tuple without 2 element then python thinks its literal type and the only way to make literal type as tuple is by adding `,` and this is the reason why we are looping through the list adding `,` to every element.

**`Try this code:`**

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, StructField, StructType
schema=StructType([StructField('name', StringType())])

data=[('anu')]

df = spark.createDataFrame([(i, )for i in data], schema)
df.show()
#+----+
#|name|
#+----+
#| anu|
#+----+
```

Comment: it's wroking but can you pls explain why you use for loop ?

Comment: check my updated answer..! its for converting your list into list of tuples..!